# Wrong usage of R package reshape2 to plot with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I would like to plot some data with ggplot2.
My data is originally in wide format, and so I would like to transform it to long format first.

Somehow "melt" produces a table I cannot use with ggplot2 as desired. 
I guess I am using it wrong, but I could sadly not find out, how to solve the problem.

I would like to plot the variables s1 and s2 vs the wavelength.
This is a minimal half working example:

```
#Generate fake data:
data <- cbind(wavelength = seq(1,10), s1 = seq(21,30), s3 = seq(41,50))

#Convert to long format:
#install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)
datLong <- melt(data          = data,
            id.vars       = c("wavelength"),
            measure.vars  = c("s1","s2"),
            variable.name = "variable",
            value.name    = "value")

#install.packages("ggplot2")
library("ggplot2")

#The following delivers the error "Error: Attempted to create layer with no stat."
 ggplot(data = datLong, mapping = aes(x = wavelength, y = value)) + layer(geom = "point") 

#This plots something, but it seems that "melt" produced a wrong format as wavelength, s1, s2 are on the x-axis.
ggplot() + layer(data = datLong, mapping = aes(x=Var2, y=value), geom = "point", stat = "identity", position_dodge(width = 3))
```

It would be very great if you could explain the problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The issue is that `data` is a matrix. So you are actually using `melt.array` and not `melt.data.frame`. The argument names differ and hence the result is not what you are looking for, see `?reshape2::melt` for details.

Comment: I'm not sure but it's rare to find a layer created as in case 1. Normally you just call the `geom` as done in my answer. Two fails because you set the x-axis to Var2(which isn't wavelength I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#or just library(tidyverse)
as.tibble(data) %>% 
  gather("Var","Val",-wavelength) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wavelength, y = Val,col=Var)) + geom_point()
```

Using `reshape2` and the `tidyverse`

```
as.tibble(data) %>% 
  melt(id.vars=c("wavelength")) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wavelength, y = value,col=variable)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: exactly what I was going to do, except maybe use `as_tibble` rather than `as.data.frame` to keep it in the `tidyverse` family.

Comment: Edited. Thanks! Used `as.tibble` though.

Comment: I'm just being picky now, but `as.tibble` is depreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfect! Still I am interested in what was the mistake I made.

Comment: @Roland it was in a non data.frame format. I've made another comment below the question. You can see this `[,1]` in the original code you provided. This suggests the data is not a dataframe. You can use `str` to see the object's data type. Use `class(data)` to see its class

Comment: @Paul. Noted. Thanks again.